# XML data to PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, xml, database, parsing, postgresql

What would be the best way to insert XML data (that I get from a webpage) into PostgreSQL database?
I'm using Java and need a little help finding a good way to read this data into the database.

Comment: when you say xml data to database, you mean you want to insert complete xml (as String/Text) or parse the fields and insert each field?

Comment: Just adding the xml file to database, or parsing values from it and saving into specific tables?

Comment: this is the data http://www.sedlabanki.is/?PageID=289

And yes, i have one table that this data should go into, that table have same column as each <mynt> have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres has (thanks to Daniel Lyons for pointing it out) [native XML support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html) which you can use to store your table. If you however want to shred your XML data manually, there are different possibilities to represent XML data in a database. The first question should be, if you want a very generic solution, that will be able to store any XML document or one that is specific to your domain (i.e. only allows XML documents of a certain structure). Depending on that, you will have a very flexible, universal representation which is however harder to query (the SQL needed will be quite complicated). If you have a more specific approach, the queries will be simpler, but you will need to create new tables or add new attributes to existing talbes every time you want to store another type of document or add a field to an existing document; so changing the schema will be harder (which is one major advantage of XML). [This presentation](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pollett/masters/Semesters/Spring06/khang/RelationalXML.ppt) should give you some ideas what are the different possibilities.

Also, you might consider to switch to some DB that supports Xquery, like [DB2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0801ledezma/). The ability to natively query using XQuery, a language targeted at processing XML, will simplify things a lot.

UPDATE: Given your comment, your XML data (that [you linked to](http://www.sedlabanki.is/?PageID=289)) is perfectly relational. It can be mapped 1:1 to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE mynt (
    ID          SERIAL     ,
    myntnafn    CHAR(3)    ,
    myntheiti   Varchar(255) ,
    kaupgengi   Decimal(15,2) ,
    midgengi    Decimal(15,2) ,
    solugengi   Decimal(15,2) ,
    dagsetning  TimeStamp      
)
```

So any `mynt` tag would be a record in the table and the corresponding sub-tags the attributes. The data types I gathered from your data, they might be wrong. The main problem is, IMO, that there is no natural primary key, so I added an autogenerated one.

Comment: [PostgreSQL has had native XML support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html) [since version 8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-xml.html).

Comment: Uh, sorry about that, assume it didn't given the question.

Comment: @Daniel: I updated it now to reflect the fact that PostgreSQL has XML. However, DB2 still has the advantage of having XQuery, from what I gathered.

Comment: Im going to use postgres but the xml data i linked in my comment above is the only kind of data that i will use. All XML that i will need to insert in my table will be like this xml so i will never net to add new attributes or anything like that. I going to google little bit more and try to find something, but if you have any idea what i can use to do this please share :). (sorry if my English is poor, not my strongest side).

Comment: @DanielLyons link broken

Comment: (Though it's not hard to find)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel they appear to be working today, but regardless, I can't edit links in a comment from four years ago, so it would be better for you to actually just leave corrected links.

Comment: @DanielLyons you're right, sorry.  Combined fault of Nepali internet and me Stack-Overflowing after about 48 straight hours of coding.

Answer (score 21):

I have a working implementation where I do *everything* inside PostgreSQL without additional libraries.

#### Auxiliary parsing function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_xml_extract_val(text, xml)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT CASE
        WHEN $1 ~ '@[[:alnum:]_]+$' THEN
           (xpath($1, $2))[1]
        WHEN $1 ~* '/text()$' THEN
           (xpath($1, $2))[1]
        WHEN $1 LIKE '%/' THEN
           (xpath($1 || 'text()', $2))[1]
        ELSE
           (xpath($1 || '/text()', $2))[1]
       END;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

#### Handle *multiple* values

The above implementation doesn't handle **multiple attributes** at one xpath. Here is an [overloaded](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html) version of `f_xml_extract_val()` for that. With the 3rd parameter you can pick `one` (the first), `all` or `dist` (distinct) values. Multiple values are aggregated to a comma-separated string.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_xml_extract_val(_path text, _node xml, _mode text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _xpath text := CASE
                   WHEN $1 ~~ '%/'              THEN $1 || 'text()'
                   WHEN lower($1) ~~ '%/text()' THEN $1
                   WHEN $1 ~ '@\w+$'            THEN $1
                   ELSE                              $1 || '/text()'
                  END;
BEGIN
   -- fetch one, all or distinct values
   CASE $3
       WHEN 'one'  THEN RETURN (xpath(_xpath, $2))[1]::text;
       WHEN 'all'  THEN RETURN array_to_string(xpath(_xpath, $2), ', ');
       WHEN 'dist' THEN RETURN array_to_string(ARRAY(
            SELECT DISTINCT unnest(xpath(_xpath, $2))::text ORDER BY 1), ', ');
       ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION
          'Invalid $3: >>%<<', $3;
   END CASE;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_xml_extract_val(text, xml, text) IS '
Extract element of an xpath from XML document
Overloaded function to f_xml_extract_val(..)
$3 .. mode is one of: one | all | dist'
```

Call:

```sql
SELECT f_xml_extract_val('//city', x, 'dist');
```

### Main part

Name of target table: `tbl`; prim. key: `id`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sync_from_xml()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
DECLARE
   datafile text := 'path/to/my_file.xml';  -- only relative path in db dir
   myxml    xml  := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); -- arbitrary 100 MB
BEGIN
   -- demonstrating 4 variants of how to fetch values for educational purposes
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp ON COMMIT DROP AS
   SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id   -- id is unique  
        , f_xml_extract_val('//col1', x)          AS col1 -- one value
        , f_xml_extract_val('//col2/', x, 'all')  AS col2 -- all values incl. dupes
        , f_xml_extract_val('//col3/', x, 'dist') AS col3 -- distinct values
   FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;

   -- 1.) DELETE?

   -- 2.) UPDATE
   UPDATE tbl t
   SET   (  col_1,   col2,   col3) =
         (i.col_1, i.col2, i.col3)
   FROM   tmp i
   WHERE  t.id = i.id
   AND   (t.col_1, t.col2, t.col3) IS DISTINCT FROM
         (i.col_1, i.col2, i.col3);

   -- 3.) INSERT NEW
   INSERT INTO tbl
   SELECT i.*
   FROM   tmp i
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id = i.id);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Important notes

- This implementation checks on a primary key if the inserted row exists already and **updates** in this case. Only new rows are inserted.
- I use a temporary staging table to speed up the procedure.
- Tested with Postgres **8.4**, **9.0** and **9.1**.
- XML has to be well-formed.
- `pg_read_file()` has restrictions to it. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE):

  > Use of these functions is restricted to superusers.

  And:

  > Only files within the database cluster directory and the `log_directory` can be accessed.

So you have to put your source file there - or create a symbolic link to your actual file/directory.

**Or** you can provide the file via Java in your case (I did it all inside Postgres).

**Or** you can import the data into 1 column of 1 row of a temporary table and take it from there.

**Or** you can use `lo_import` like demonstrated in this [related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8172/sql-to-read-xml-from-file-into-postgresql-database/8188#8188).

- [SQL to read XML from file into PostgreSQL database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8188/3684)

This blog [post by Scott Bailey](https://scottrbailey.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/xml-parsing-postgres/) helped me.

Comment: what i  must do if the xml rows contain reserved character such as "'" or "&"??

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL has an [XML datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html). There are lots of [XML specific functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-xml.html) you can use to query and modify the data, such as with xpath.

From the Java side, you can pretend you're just working with strings, but know that the data is well-formed on the way out and it won't let you store non-well-formed data.