# Extracting value of xml tag in PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, casting, xml-parsing

Below is the column response from my Postgres table.  I want to extract the status from all the rows in my Postgres database. The status could be of varying sizes like `SUCCESS` as well so I do not want to use the substring function. Is there a way to do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>ERROR_MISSING_DATA</status><responseType>COUNTRY_MISSING</responseType><country_info>USA</country_info><phone_country_code>1234</phone_country_code></response>
```

so my table structure is like this

```
   Column    |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         

-------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------

 id          | bigint                      | not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 hostname    | text                        | not null
 time        | timestamp without time zone | not null
 trn_type    | text                        | 
 db_ret_code | text                        | 
 request     | text                        | 
 response    | text                        | 
 wait_time   | text                        |
```

And I want to extract status from each and every request.  How do i do this?

Below is a sample row.  And assume the table name abc_events

```
id          | 1870667
hostname    | abcd.local
time        | 2013-04-16 00:00:23.861
trn_type    | A
request     | <?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>ERROR_MISSING_DATA</status><responseType>COUNTRY_MISSING</responseType><country_info>USA</country_info><phone_country_code>1234</phone_country_code></response>
response    | <?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>ERROR_MISSING_DATA</status><responseType>COUNTRY_MISSING</responseType><country_info>USA</country_info><phone_country_code>1234</phone_country_code></response>
```

Comment: request has the xml request and response has the xml response.  And the xml that I have shown above is an example of the response.  Essentially I am trying to extract the status tag from each and every xml response row.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [**`xpath()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) function:

```
WITH x(col) AS (SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>ERROR_MISSING_DATA</status></response>'::xml)
SELECT xpath('./status/text()', col) AS status
FROM   x
```

`/text()` strips the surrounding `<status>` tag.
Returns an array of `xml` - with a single element in this case:

```
status
xml[]
-------
{ERROR_MISSING_DATA}
```

#### Applied to your table

In response to your question update, this can simply be:

```
SELECT id, xpath('./status/text()', response::xml) AS status
FROM   tbl;
```

If you are certain there is only a single status tag per row, you can simply extract the first item from the array:

```
SELECT id, (xpath('./status/text()', response::xml))[1] AS status
FROM   tbl;
```

If there can be multiple status items:

```
SELECT id, unnest(xpath('./status/text()', response::xml)) AS status
FROM   tbl;
```

Gets you 1-n rows per `id`.

#### Cast to `xml`

Since you defined your columns to be of type `text` (instead of [**`xml`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-xml.html), you **need** to cast to `xml` explicitly. The function `xpath()` expects the 2nd parameters of type `xml`. An untyped string constant is coerced to `xml` automatically, but a **`text` column** is not. You need to cast explicitly.

This works without explicit cast:

```
  SELECT xpath('./status/text()'
      ,'<?xml version="1.0" ?><response><status>SUCCESS</status></response>')
```

A **CTE** like in my first example *needs* a type for every column in the "common table expression". If I had not cast to a specific type, the type `unknown` would have been used - which is *not* the same thing as an *untyped string*. Obviously, there is no direct conversion implemented between `unknown` and `xml`. You'd have to cast to `text` first: `unknown_type_col::text::xml`. Better to cast to `::xml` right away.

This has been tightened with PostgreSQL 9.1 (I think). Older versions were more permissive.

Either way, with any of these methods the string has to be *valid xml* or the cast (implicit or explicit) will raise an exception.

Comment: Do you need the `::xml`? I was just doing `SELECT xpath('...', '<raw>xml</raw>');` and it seems to work.

Comment: I edited my question.  Essentially what I want is to extract value of a tag from the column that has the xml request/response.

Comment: I followed it but I am getting this error
`LINE 1: select unnest(xpath('./status/text()', request)) from abc_events

                      ^

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

It is pointing to the xpath function.

Comment: @Phrogz: I added a chapter on the topic of casting, since my initial comment wasn't completely correct. A cast is actually *needed* with a CTE in this case ...

Comment: @ronak: I added a bit to my answer. Note the addendum about casting to xml. Also note I had the wrong cast at first. Must be `::xml`.

Comment: @ronak: Cool. :) For more advanced acrobatics with `xpath()` consider [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491479/xml-data-to-postgresql-database/7628453#7628453).

Comment: But what if there is multiple tags in a column? How i can extract them?
Suppose xml-data in a column is like -
    <status>abc</status><response>ERROR_MISSING_DATA</response>

Comment: Hi, simple "cast XML to text"  must use `//text()`... So `array_to_string( xpath('path//text()', xcontent)::text[] , '')` to obtain all text from, eg., the TXT of an HTML document.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><BookList xmlns="http://www.azkhaban.com/DEM-ON-TOR-20040511#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.hogwarts.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.p07.org/1989/XMLSchema-instance"><status>ERROR_MISSING_DATA</status></BookList>

When the xml is something like this how can I get the xpath?
For every entry in the table the urls may not be the same so I cannot keep the url as a part of the xpath right?