# Postgresql: Using xpath to extract data from an XML column

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I've been trying to extract values from XML the same way as *@Erwin Brandstetter* answered a few times with an accepted answer, but it just doesn't work for me:

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023523/extracting-value-of-xml-tag-in-postgresql) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799790/using-xpath-to-extract-data-from-an-xml-column-in-postgres) this should work, but I just get an **empty** result:

```
WITH x AS ( SELECT
   '<Attributes xmlns="http://www.gis34.dk">
        <bemaerkning displayName="Bemærkning">Beatrix</bemaerkning>
        <billede displayName="Billede">https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/killbill/images/3/39/The_Bride.jpg</billede>
    </Attributes>'::xml AS t
)

SELECT xpath('/Attributes/bemaerkning/text()', t) as comment
FROM   x
```

Result:
(expected: {My comment})

```
comment
xml[]
-------
{}
```

My database version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.5.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2, 64-bit
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799790/using-xpath-to-extract-data-from-an-xml-column-in-postgres

Comment: @har07, this link was one of the two references in my question... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your XML defines a namespace, and that namespace must be used in the xpath expression.

```
SELECT xpath('/g:Attributes/g:bemaerkning/text()', t, array[array['g','http://www.gis34.dk']]) as comment
FROM   x
```

Note the third parameter that [passes a two-dimensional array of namespace mappings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING).

The `xpath()` function returns an array of elements. If you know you only get a single element (or only ever want the first one) you just return the first element of the array:

```
SELECT (xpath('/g:Attributes/g:bemaerkning/text()', t, array[array['g','http://www.gis34.dk']])[1] as comment
FROM   x
```

Note the parentheses around the function call: `(xpath(...))`

Comment: That's great. One more thing, is it possible to retrieve the text without the curly braces surrounding them?

Comment: @Ambran: `xpath()` returns an array, just use the first element. See my edit