# Possible namespace issue with xpath query

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath, xml-namespaces

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080743/postgresql-using-xpath-to-extract-data-from-an-xml-column) as a reference to creating the below `xpath` query in `postgresql`.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT message::xml as res
            FROM messages_table a
                WHERE a.id = '123'
                AND a.service = 'MY_SERVICE'
                AND a.call_type = 'RESPONSE'
)
SELECT xpath('/g:Message/g:Result/text()', res, array[array['g','http://www.nw.co.uk/ni/ws/2004/02/Standard']]) as result
-- SELECT res
FROM cte;
```

I get this result:

```
result
xml[]
-------
{}
```

My `XML` has this opening tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message
     Type="Response"
     Version="1"
     xmlns:dp="nw.co.uk:dp-1"
     xmlns:nu="http://www.nw.co.uk/ni/ws/2004/02/Standard">
    <Result
         Completed="Y"
         ErrorCount="0"
         Ref="RF">
        <Data
             Type="Output"
             dp:Instance="1">
            <Item dp:Instance="1">
                <Item_Class Val="5"/>
                <Item_Rate Val="1"/>
                <Item_Age Val="45.68306"/>
                <Item_AgeOfYoungestDriver Val="150"/>
                <Item_No Val="2"/>
            </Item>
            <Item dp:Instance="2">
                <Item_Age Val="0"/>
                <Item_No Val="0"/>
            </Item>
        </Data>
    </Result>
</Message>
```

Is my issue in some way related to the fact that I seem to have two namespace attributes? If so how do I resolve this?

Comment: There's nothing odd about having two namespace attributes - they're defining different prefixes, for different namespaces. Inside that element, any name prefixed `dp:` is in namespace `nw.co.uk:dp-1`, and any name prefixed `nu:` is in namespace `http://www.nw.co.uk/ni/ws/2004/02/Standard` (which is the one you've given prefix `g` in your XPath query). Without a bigger sample of the XML, it's pretty hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Ah, I assume I could have `array[array['nu',http://www.nw.co.uk/ni/ws/2004/02/Standard'], array['dp', 'nw.co.uk:dp-1']]`

Comment: Yeah, I imagine so (I don't know the Potgres functions specifically). Note that you don't have to use those prefixes, you can use whatever makes sense to you; it's the _values_ that have to match the XML document. Again, a proper [mcve] would allow someone to give you a full answer.

Comment: I included an expanded xml example. It's still massively reduced but too big to include all here.

Comment: I don't see any `PolMessage` or `TranResult` in that example. The example doesn't need to be the full thing, just enough of it to show the structure you're expecting the expression to match.

Comment: Sorry, updated that now.

Answer (score 0):

XML namespaces are a way of distinguishing multiple elements with the same name, so that you can combine multiple XML schemas in one document. Each namespace is identified by a URI (just as a way of "owning" the namespace), which you can think of as part of the "full name" of an element or attribute.

If we write the "full name" as `{namespaceURI}ElementName`, the following are all possible "full names":

- `Example`
- `{https://example.com}Example`
- `{urn:example}Example`

There are two ways a namespace can be associated to an element:

- If an element has an attribute `xmlns`, e.g. `xmlns="https://example.com"` then all *unprefixed* elements inside it have that namespace; this is referred to as a "default namespace"
- If an element has an attribute starting `xmlns:`, e.g. `xmlns:example="https://example.com"`, then elements are in that namespace if they have the given prefix; so, the namespace of `<example:Foo>` is determined by the attribute `xmlns:example`

In your document:

- There is no `xmlns` attribute, so elements with no prefix *are not in any namespace* (they are effectively in the "null" namespace)
- There is an `xmlns:dp` attribute, so any element prefixed `dp:` is in namespace `nw.co.uk:dp-1`
- There is an `xmlns:nu` attribute, so any element prefixed `nu:` is in namespace `http://www.nw.co.uk/ni/ws/2004/02/Standard`

In XPath, you can use whatever prefixes you want for the namespaces you want to access. The important thing is the actual URI they look up to.

The elements you are trying to access are `<Message>` and `<Result>`. They are not prefixed `nu`, so are not in the `http://www.nw.co.uk/ni/ws/2004/02/Standard` namespace; that's why your XPath doesn't find them.

Since they have no prefix, and no default namespace is defined, `<Message>` and `<Result>` are not in any namespace, so you probably just want this:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT message::xml as res
            FROM messages_table a
                WHERE a.id = '123'
                AND a.service = 'MY_SERVICE'
                AND a.call_type = 'RESPONSE'
)
SELECT xpath('/Message/Result/text()', res) as result
-- SELECT res
FROM cte;
```