# XML File parsing placed on Unix Path

Tags: postgresql, unix, xml-parsing

I have a XML file which is placed on a unix location, say: /home/bojack/SourceFiles/data_file.xml

I want to parse this xml file using postgres. Is there any way to do this?

Whenever xml file is part of a column value in postgres table, we can use XMLTABLE inbuild function of postgres to parse, is there any way we can use directly unix path to point to xml file and start parsing it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2009/02/importing-xml-content-from-file/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import XML files to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007884/import-xml-files-to-postgresql)