# Load simple XML file into Postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql, parsing, load

I have a file with a simple xml structure that I want to load into a Postgres table.

```
<rows>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="age">75-84</field>
<field name="gndr">F</field>
<field name="inc">32000-47999</field>
</rows>
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to throw it into a blob, or parse it out into a normalized table structure?  What tool do you want to use (Perl, Java, etc.)?

Comment: Trying to parse into a normalized table. If PostGres doesn't have a function to take care of the parsing, Python would be my first choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it *can* be done. I wrote a complete function for the same purpose a while back:

- [XML data to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491479/xml-data-to-postgresql-database/7628453#7628453)

I use [pg_read_file()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE) to read in the whole file into a variable in plpgsql and proceed from there. This carries a few restrictions:

> Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory
>   can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster
>   directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting
>   for log files. Use of these functions is restricted to superusers.

But I listed alternatives.

If you can convert the XML file to JSON it gets simpler. [There are a bunch of tools for that available](https://www.google.at/search?q=convert%20xml%20to%20json).

Starting with Postgres **9.3** you get pretty good support for the `json` data type.
Better yet, use the `jsonb` data type in Postgres **9.4+**.

- [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)